# How can I make the user location centered in a Map but allow free movement?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit, core-location

I have a `UIViewController` that uses a `MapKit`:

This is my viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

   EventsmapMapView.delegate = self;
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

   EventsmapMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
   [EventsmapMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
   [EventsmapMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
   [EventsmapMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

}
```

And this is the delegate method `didUpdateUserLocation` :

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

   MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 5000, 5000);
   [self.EventsmapMapView setRegion:[self.EventsmapMapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

Basically my issue is that when the View loads, I can locate myself in the map, but then I am not able to move around the map. What happens is that every time I move around, the map automatically locates me again. I am aware that the issue is in `didUpdateUserLocation` but I am not sure how to modify the code to prevent this behavior. Pretty sure it's something relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `isInitialized` property.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isInitialized;
```

Add **Guard Clause**

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

    if (self.isInitialized) {
        return;
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 5000, 5000);
[self.EventsmapMapView setRegion:[self.EventsmapMapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    self.isInitialized = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `didUpdateUserLocation:`, you called `setRegion:animated:` which will change the visible region to your current location, and because you were not moving. Then you ended up being locking.

You may consider the following approach (not test):

First, define a panning state flag

```
BOOL isMapPanning;
```

Init a pan gesture recognizer with target pointed to your view

```
panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[EventsmapMapView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

And a gesture handler

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            // Stop map updating...
            isMapPanning = YES;
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            // ... until panning is stop
            isMapPanning = NO;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, whenever `CLLocationManager` calls your `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate, just check for the panning flag before doing all the stuffs.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
   if (!isMapPanning) {
       MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 5000, 5000);
       [self.EventsmapMapView setRegion:[self.EventsmapMapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
   }
}
```